# How to structure ASP.NET MVC action method to receive posted JSON in different formats?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

A 3rd party will be posting JSON data to my MVC application, and because the format of the JSON will vary depending on what kind of data is sent, I cannot create a single ViewModel representation of the JSON data and make that my argument.

I need to be able to structure my Action method to handle any format of JSON sent ... and the question is, how?

Comment: don't you have the property names upfront?

Comment: no.  the incoming json will be structured completely differently depending upon what kind of notification the 3rd party sends. i feel like what I need is some kind of totally generic dictionary as a model???